# How can i change my "read more" to an image with hover effect?

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently editing my premade layout downloaded in the internet and i would like to edit the "Read More" link to an image.

The best example that i want to achieve is like in the website of 
[www.hongkiat.com](http://hongkiat.com). When you hover Continue Reading, the background changes.

my code in the template is this:

```
<div class="entry">
<p><?php the_content('Read More...'); ?></p>
</div><!--entry-->
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: After asking question you should accept any of the answer.It is Good to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an [HTML `<img>` tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Adding_An_Image) as a parameter:

```
<?php the_content('Read more...<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_directory'). '/images/leaf.gif" alt="read more" title="Read more..." />'); ?>
```

Comment: Hi Pat,thank you for your answer. I also saw that  code in wordpress forums. The problem with that code is that there is no hover effect on it. I want to achieve an image Read more with hover effect. thank you!

Comment: You'd need to add mouseover/mouseout behaviour to do that.  Using the above with something like this would do the trick: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex15/domroll.htm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have

```
<div class="entry">
<p><?php the_content('<span class="readmore">Read More...</span>'); ?></p>
</div><!--entry-->
```

You can add a behavior in CSS like so:

```
span.readmore{background-color:red}
```